# Valid relative path for dlopen() on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, xlib, dlopen, x11

```
getcwd( buff, 1024);
```

says current following working path; what should I do?

```
buff = "/home/online0227/my project/Tutorial/Tutorial 1 Device Seletion\0"
```

---

I am trying to load my `.so` file using following function on Linux
but they all fail.  What is correct path to describe the path to my `.so` file?

```
   m_hSO = ::dlopen("..//..//..//..//..//so//myso.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   if(!m_hSO) {
   m_hSO = ::dlopen("..//..//..//..//..//so/myso.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   }
   if(!m_hSO) {
   m_hSO = ::dlopen("../../../../../so/myso.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   }
   if(!m_hSO) {
   m_hSO = ::dlopen("..//..//so/myso.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   }
```

Comment: Always use -at least for debugging- `dlerror` when `dlopen` fails: `fprintf(stderr, "dlopen fails %s\n", dlerror());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider using the path separator "/" and not "//". I don't believe that any bad effects will come from using "//" but "/" should suffice.
2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and have that include the location of your shared library. This is the best way to make sure that `dlopen()` (or `::dlopen()`) find your library. Remember that 'relative paths' are relative to the current working directory and that really depends on the current working directory when the program is launched and any changes to current working directory by any code up to the point when `::dlopen()` is called.
3. As to why your program is failing to find the .so when you call `::dlopen()` you should call `getcwd()` and find out what it says. That will help you adjust the relative path. But, let me reiterate that this is a bad practice unless you have some very good reason to do so.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: omg. I just implemented what you said, getcwd(), and it says:buff = \"/home/online0227/project/Tutorial/Tutorial 1 Device Seletion\\000\\\"\\275\\357\\377\\377t:\\336\\367\\377\\177\\000\\000\\001\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\00367\\377\\177\\000\\000\\360\\347\\377\\177\\000\\000\\f\\217\\000\\360\\000\\a\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\00\\...

Comment: in this case what should i do haha

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison, I've tried to reword the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: The path stops at the `\000` (or `\\000` as you wrote it).  After that, the debugger is just going bonkers.